# AngularJs Ng-Repeat Accessing an Array within an Array (without nested ng-repeat)

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I want to access the data within an array within an array, without using nested ng-repeats because when I do this it shows the content I only want to display once multiple times. I want to make an ng-repeat that only cyles through the data in my inner most arrays, while still being aware of what outer array's data it is housed in so that it will change on the users click. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rightSection">
    <form>
        <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Submit Idea</a></div>
    </form>
    <div id="list2"  class="list-group">
        <div id="generalInfo">
            <d2 id="productViewerTitle">{{productViewer.title}}</d2>
            <br/>
            <p id="productViewerRating" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">{{productViewer.rating}}</p>
            <p id="productViewerUsers">{{productViewer.users}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></p>
            <br/>
            <p id="productViewerLanguage">{{productViewer.tool}}</p>
            <br/>
            <div id="bigImageHolder"><img id="productViewerImage" src={{productViewer.image}} alt=""/></div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <div id="longDescriptionSection">
            <p id="productViewerDescription">{{productViewer.description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div id="jobListings">
            <div id="jobTitle">
                <p id="availableJobsTitle">Available Jobs</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="jobsContainer" ng-repeat="product in products">
                    <div id="jobHolder" ng-repeat="job in product.jobs">
                        <p id="jobName">{{productViewer.title}}</p>
                        <p id="jobPay">{{job.pay}}</p>
                        <p id="jobDifficulty">Difficutly: {{job.difficulty}}</p>
                        <p id="jobCredential" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">{{job.credential}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {

    $('#signUpButton').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $('#signUpForm').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
        });
    });
    $('#logInButton').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $('#logInForm').animate({'top':'160px'},500);
        });
    });
    $('#boxCloseLogIn').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#logInForm').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){

        });
    });
    $('#boxCloseSignUp').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#signUpForm').animate({'top':'-500px'},500,function(){

        });
    });

});


//Dropdowns

//$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
//    var selText = $(this).text();
//    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
//});

$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

    $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');

});




angular.module("findAProject", [])

    .controller("projectFinderPage", function($scope) {

        $scope.relevance = '-rating';
        $scope.tools = '-tool';
        $scope.topic = '-topic';
        $scope.info = function(product) {
            $scope.productViewer = product;
        };
        $scope.jobListings = function(product) {
            $scope.jobViewer = product;
        };

        $scope.products = [
                {title:'Proper Plants Website Redesign',
                image:'http://www.interactive-biology.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Pea-Plant11.jpg',
                description:'Help redesign the layout of Proper Plants based in Kentucky!',
                tool:'HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT',
                users:321,
                rating:100,
                topic:"TECHNOLOGY",
                jobs:[
                    {name: 'Backend Engineering', difficulty: 'Hard', credential: 'Knowledge of SQL backend logging', pay: '1000'},
                    {name: 'Object Color Correction', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Ability to normalize color ranges', pay: '50'},
                    {name: 'AngularJs Implementation', difficulty: 'Medium', credential: 'Understanding of ngRepeat and ngSort', pay: '100'},
                    {name: 'Advertisement', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Ability to effectively market to 100+', pay: '150'},
                    {name: 'Title UI Redesign', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Can make a functional logo redesign', pay: '50'},
                    {name: 'SQL System Management', difficulty: 'Very Hard', credential: "Ability to maintain a parsed server", pay: '1500'},
                    {name: 'Facebook Page Management', difficulty: 'Very Easy', credentials: 'Basic social skills', pay: '25/w'},
                    {name: 'Competitor Market Research', difficulty: 'Medium', credentials: 'Marketing Degree', pay:'120'},
                    {name: "TESTING TESTING", difficulty: "Medium", credentials: "None", pay:"10"}]},
            {title:'Tiper Logo Redesign', image:'http://site.xavier.edu/polt/typewriters/underwood5small.jpg', description:'Be a part of the team making the new Tiper logo!', tool:'PHOTOSHOP', users:3, rating:13, topic:"TECHNOLOGY",
                jobs: [{name: 'Backend Engineering', difficulty: 'Hard', credential: 'Knowledge of SQL backend logging', pay: '1000'},
                    {name: 'TEST', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Ability to normalize color ranges', pay: '50'},
                    {name: 'AngularJs Implementation', difficulty: 'Medium', credential: 'Understanding of ngRepeat and ngSort', pay: '100'},
                    {name: 'Advertisement', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Ability to effectively market to 100+', pay: '150'},
                    {name: 'Title UI Redesign', difficulty: 'Easy', credential: 'Can make a functional logo redesign', pay: '50'},
                    {name: 'SQL System Management', difficulty: 'Very Hard', credential: "Ability to maintain a parsed server", pay: '1500'},
                    {name: 'Facebook Page Management', difficulty: 'Very Easy', credentials: 'Basic social skills', pay: '25/w'},
                    {name: 'Competitor Market Research', difficulty: 'Medium', credentials: 'Marketing Degree', pay:'120'}]},
            {title:'Random Project', image:'http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/zxpvsmndjrroklechbz4.gif', description:'This is some random proejct.', tool:'C++', users:233, rating: 17},
            {title:'Vent Design Logo', image:'https://m2.behance.net/rendition/pm/17643109/disp/b2b102b8772bb0cefd73e957ce73382b.png', description:'Help us with our company logo.', tool:'PHOTOSHOP', users:6, rating:34},
            {title:'Neopets Reloaded', image:'http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/neopets-6.jpg', description:'Be apart of the team working on the next big thing in Neopets!', tool:'HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT', users:444, rating:1113},
            {title:'New York Times Website', image:'http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5399cc0ae4b0705199b37aa3/5399e8a2e4b0f44ec1b1e21e/545a0216e4b05115df2de008/1429793622682/?format=1500w', description:'Help us redesign the New York Times Website', tool:'PHOTOSHOP', users:13, rating:243},
            {title:'Animal Counting Algorithm', image:'http://phoenixzoo.org/wordpress/wp-content/galleries/animals-gallery-2/phoenix-zoo-animals-17.jpg', description:'We need a complex algorithm to count our animals!', tool:'C++', users:8, rating:93},
            {title:'Racing Videogame (Racers 2)', image:'http://coolcarswallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/32-aston-martin-v12-zagato-racecar-red-white-car-1080x1920.jpg', description:'Time to buld a racing videogame for PC and Mac!', tool:'C#', users:39, rating:63},
            {title:'Trash Location App', image:'http://www.ozarkalabama.org/ozark/Portals/0/trash-symbol.jpg', description:'We are making an app to help garbage men locate trash!', tool:'C#', users:5, rating:27}
        ];

        $scope.productViewer = '';
        $scope.jobViewer = '';

    })

        .directive("navBar", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: "nav-bar.html"
            };
        })

        .directive("titleArea", function() {
            return {
                restict: "E",
                templateUrl: "title-area.html"
            };
        })

        .directive("leftSide", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: "left-side.html"
            };
        })

        .directive("rightSide", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "E",
                templateUrl: "right-side.html"
            };
        })
```

So in essence I want to make it so when I have clicked on an element of the products array I can display just the information in the jobs array of that clicked products array in an ng-repeat.

Comment: You need to flatten the data by implementing custom filter..and then do `ng-repeat` on flatten data

Comment: Any way you could elaborate more on this?